# Pronouncing "Cothelstone"

Tags: pronunciation

A legendary sketch by German humor giant Loriot has a poor TV lady trying to announce a British telenovela. Expectably, "th" totally pwns her. But the vowels are a problem either: "North Cothelstone Hall" comes out as five medium length "o" sounds by her. I wanted to know what is correct but even for the "stone" part, as checked via [here](https://www.pronouncekiwi.com/Cothelstone), there was an amazing variety. (Whereas I expected long o, short a, schwa, ou, long o, EOD.)

Any resident of lovely Cothelstone here? :-) (Or at least someone of the Somerset vicinity.)

Comment: You can hear in pronounced here https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=1002308277212095

Comment: @JamesK - what's the betting you could find some bearded old codger who says "Oo Arr, that's how they posh Lunnon (or Bristol, or Taunton) folk says it, we says 'Cuttlestun'?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

James K's link is terrific - just the thing!

@ Hauke: what is the variety you find regarding the pronunciation of "stone"? Are you considering local dialects too?

Your rationalization of the sounds is pretty close. In RP (as in James' video by the BBC) "Cothelsone" is made up of two (possibly three syllables, depending on the speaker) with the following vowels:

1. Co-     an open back rounded vowel, as in "not" /nɒt/; this syllable receives
   the main stress of the word;
2. -thel-  a schwa sound /θəl/ which is extremely reduced or not pronounced; if
   pronounced, it sounds close to /ʊ/ due to the "dark l" following;
3. -stone  this is the diphtong /stəʊn/, as in "phone", or "most".

The original question is however about a compound, i.e. Cothelstone Hall. In British English:

4. Hall    has the same vowel sound /ɔː/ as "door", "thought" and "law". The final
   consonant is again a dark /l/.
5. North   I was forgetting this: same vowel as Hall of course.

I hope the above helps.

Comment: You've submitted the same question twice. It can happen by accident especially when you use "back" and "forward" while editing. I've deleted your less recent one. If that's the one you'd rather keep, feel free to fix it :)

Comment: Concerning dialects: isn't the "official" pronunciation just the dialect that most people agree on? :-) The point is, of course, in the link I posted I heard six different speakers, and had no idea what is most close to standard. (Although I was fairly sure st-schwa probably isn't...)

Comment: idk the case for Cothelstone, but sometimes the locals will insist it's pronounced one way & the owner another - as they originate from opposite ends of the British 'class system'. One that keeps us amused is Harewood House. It is owned by Lord 'Harr-wood' but the house itself is pronounced 'hair-wood' & ne'er the twain shall meet.

Comment: @gonefishin'again - it's a minefield. Cirencester/Cissester, Bosham/Bozzum  out of dozens that I have heard of. Allesley in Coventry is 'Awsley'. There's an apocryphal tale of an American tourist asking for a rail ticket to 'Looga Barooga' which turned out to be Loughborough.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - maybe he was on his way to Whirr Sester or Lie Sester, via Haw Wick. [Wuster, Lester & Hoyk for the non Brits]

Comment: May I ask what the downvote is due to? I do agree that my answer needs editing.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann - I was using the term "dialect" in the Greek, neutral sense of "language". As for an "official" pronunciation: general agreement would be nice, but what ends up as "official" is just the version adopted by speakers who have cultural (and /or political) clout. :) That's traditionally the speech of the South-East  (well represented in the BBC video). As for local pronunciations, you would need to ask a historical linguist! :) The diphtong /stəʊn/ does contain schwa /ə/ by the way. Does the above answer your question?

Comment: @suzumushiyh: Together with the comments, definitely. (Here in Germany we *do* have dialect too, naturally - I live in "Hamboach" :-) But I guess it's much less pronounced.)